# Python 3: Remove curly brakets from value in dictionary output

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dict where the keys map to a previous variable:

```
{5: {'N_Fixation'},
 6: {'Nitrification'},
 7: {'Denitrification'},
 8: {'N_Assimilation'},
 9: {'Anammox'}}
```

For example, if the user previously selected the number five, my desired output is to print:

```
You have selected N_Fixation
```

But the output is always the value in curly brackets:

```
You have selected {'N_Fixation'}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You are defining a `set` as the value. Remove the `{}` around the values in your dict. eg `{5: 'N_Fixation', 6: 'Nitrification', ...}`

Comment: @Tim. Yeah! turns out that I previously had a tuple and I converted it into a dict using a wrong method. Thanks!